# Capistrano's /current folder always points to the same (non-existent) release

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

My capistrano release appears to be "sucked", since no matter how many `cap production deploy`s I send, the /current folder is generated over and over again pointing to the same folder.

```
# Trying to open /current with FTP Sync
Command:    CWD /public_html/storekey-demo/releases/20180813141339
Response:   550 /public_html/storekey-demo/releases/20180813141339: No such file or directory
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Even after deleting the /current folder, the /releases folder, the /repo folder, the /temp folder, and the revisions.log file, and running `capistrano` again, the symlink is created pointing to the same folder. I think I've tried everything I can think of.

This is my deploy.rb file

```
lock "~> 3.11.0"

set :application, "storekey_demo" # don't use "-"
set :repo_url, "git@gitlab.com: xxxxxxxxxxx .git"

set :deploy_to, "/home/u0000000/public_html/storekey-demo"
set :tmp_dir, '/home/u0000000/public_html/tmp'


namespace :deploy do
    desc "Build"
    after :updated, :build do
        on roles(:web) do
            within release_path do
                execute :composer, "install --no-dev --quiet --optimize-autoloader"
            end
        end
    end
end

namespace :deploy do
    desc "Copy Env"
    after :finished, :copy do
        on roles(:all) do
            upload! "production.env", "#{current_path}/.env"
        end
    end
end
```

This is my deploy log, as you can see there are no errors

```
> cap production deploy
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /home/u000000000/public_html/tmp
    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 7.806s
      Uploading /home/u000000000/public_html/tmp/git-ssh-storekey_demo-production-francisco.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /home/u000000000/public_html/tmp/git-ssh-storekey_demo-production-francisco.sh
    ✔ 02 u000000000@185.201.11.23 0.445s
00:09 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@gitlab.com: xxxxxx .git HEAD
      01 75bb7ded165efb968f00d29808b0673d7517aa41       HEAD
    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 1.438s
00:10 deploy:check:directories
      01 mkdir -p /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo/shared /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo/releases
    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 0.399s
00:12 git:clone
      The repository mirror is at /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo/repo
00:12 git:update
      01 git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com: xxxxxxx .git
    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 0.465s
      02 git remote update --prune
      02 Fetching origin
    ✔ 02 u000000000@185.201.11.23 1.537s
00:15 git:create_release
      01 mkdir -p /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo/releases/20180813165948
    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 0.455s
      02 git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo/releases/20180813165948
    ✔ 02 u000000000@185.201.11.23 6.387s
00:23 deploy:set_current_revision
      01 echo "75bb7ded165efb968f00d29808b0673d7517aa41" > REVISION
    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 0.443s
00:24 deploy:build
      01 composer install --no-dev --quiet --optimize-autoloader
    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 6.045s
00:30 deploy:symlink:release
      01 ln -s /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo/releases/20180813165948 /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo/releases/current
    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 25.267s
      02 mv /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo/releases/current /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo
    ✔ 02 u000000000@185.201.11.23 0.421s
00:56 deploy:cleanup
      Keeping 5 of 6 deployed releases on 185.201.11.23
      01 rm -rf /home/u000000000/public_html/storekey-demo/releases/20180813164636
    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 0.543s
00:58 deploy:log_revision
      01 echo "Branch master (at 75bb7ded165efb968f00d29808b0673d7517aa41) deployed as release 20180813165948 by francisco" >> /home/u000000000/publ…

    ✔ 01 u000000000@185.201.11.23 0.530s
00:59 deploy:copy
      Uploading production.env 100.0%
```

Comment: I have the same config as you. Did you get this error? SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as : scp: /public_html/app/current/20181122233252/.env: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem was in FileZilla itself, and not in capistrano.

I entered through the SSH console in my server and deleted the /current symlink, then created it again pointing to the last build, and run `capistrano production deploy`. The problem is fixed and changes are being deployed correctly, but FireZilla is still not recognizing the symlink correctly.